# Can you overwrite / substitute "self" for another variable in the method?

Tags: python

I'm trying to build a function that I can use to recursively find parent links, but in order to do so, I need to call on the get_ancestors() function using the parent variable after the first iteration, rather than the self variable. Is this breaking some sort of rule?

```
    def get_ancestors(self, ancestors):
        parents = []
        for uid in self.links:
            parents.append(self.tree.find_item(uid))
        for parent in parents:
            if parent.links:
                self.get_ancestors(parent, ancestors)
            else:
                if parent not in ancestors:
                    ancestors.append(parent)
        return ancestors
```

Comment: `self` is usually the object that the method is called on - could you call `parent.get_ancestors(ancestors)`?

Comment: You would use `parent.get_ancestors(X)` for the recursive calls.

Comment: `self.get_ancestors(parent, ancestors)` will get an error because it passes too many arguments. It's equivalent to `Classname.get_ancestors(self, parent, ancestors)`

Comment: this is confusing. Why would get_ancestors() be in instance method (takes a `self` argument) in the children but not be an instance method in the parent? If get_ancestors() is a class method in the parent, how would you use `self` (no matter how you define it or try to assign/substitute it?)

Comment: @Luke this works! thank you so much, makes total sense; still new to the programming game

Comment: @topsail I totally understand, and I'm not entirely sure if the approach I'm taking makes sense or will lead me to my goal. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72604408/how-to-pass-python-function-to-template-where-the-parameter-is-a-variable-that-i This might give some more context as to what I'm trying to do with this method (although I have made some minor changes to the code since then)

Comment: Okay nevermind, I was thinking it wasn't working still!